# spotlessDiagnose diverges after 10 steps message

Tags: java, gradle, spotless

**spotlessDiagnose** diverges after 10 steps message, is seen and doesn't let us modify **importOrder** across all files. How do we resolve this

```
gradlew spotlessDiagnose

> Task :spotlessJavaDiagnose
    src/main/java/com/foo/repository/Foo.java diverges after 10 steps
    src/main/java/com/foo/repository/Bar.java diverges after 10 steps
```

My definition looks like this

```
spotless {
    java {
        importOrder()
    }   
}
```

Comment: Check if this helps: https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/blob/main/PADDEDCELL.md

Comment: I do understand how it works, I have attached my definition above. I want to understand how to go about fixing this